# Why Function is getting accessed without object in C++?

Tags: c++

In the following program.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


class Base{


public:
    Base(){
    cout<<"I am Constructor"<<endl;
    }
    void method();


};

void Base::method(){
cout<<"I am method"<<endl;
}

int main()
{

    Base *sc1;
    Base *sc2;
    sc1->method();
    sc2->method();


}
```

the output I am getting is as follows

```
I am method
I am method
```

How can this happen as no object is created?

Answer (score 5):

It is undefined behaviour, so "anything" can happen. It probably runs because you do not access anything (implicitly or explicitly) via the `this` pointer.

This would be more likely to fail:

```
struct Foo
{
  int foo() const { return i; } 
  int i;
};

int main()
{
  Foo* f;
  f->foo();
}
```

Comment: I like that you have mentioned that it probably "works" because no member data is accessed. Was about to write an example before you edited yours. I had already voted for your answer so you will have to imagine my bonus point! :)

Answer (score 3):

Because you have no object your code has *Undefined Behaviour*. Undefined behaviour means exactly what it says, it doesn't mean your program will crash, it means anything can happen, including accessing an object that doesn't exist.

One of the things that makes programming C++ hard is that you cannot rely on bugged programs to crash, sometimes they seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

This is undefined behavior, but it is not crashing because you are not accessing any member variables from that class so even if the pointer `sc1`/`sc2` is random value nothing is happening.